# How to display array line by line by pressing Enter

Tags: java

the scope of this problem is to have each element of the array displayed when I hit Enter.
I came across `System.in.read()` method and it kind of works but if I type a bunch of random characters and then hit enter it will not only display the next line but displays several elements in a row... I have tried different ways of solving it but to no avail.
Hopefully, someone can at least point me in the right direction.
Below is my simplified code.
Thanks

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class classClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        System.in.read();
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you already imported `java.util.Scanner`, you could just use Scanner's `.nextLine()` method like so:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int[] array = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to read the entire line. `System.in.read()` only reads the next character.